# User favorites file comparison

Tags: file-management, rating

I am searching for a simple piece of software that shows me two random files  (for example photos or MP3s) and asks me which I like best. After a while it should be able to order the files from most favorite to least favorite for me personally.

I have a preference for Android, but Windows would be fine, too. Gratis would be awesome, but I am willing to pay for it.